# docker python package 4.3.1 not working with Docker Desktop 4.12.0 on Windows 10

Tags: python, docker

The error I was getting on executing **container.exec_run()** method, when upgraded to Docker Desktop 4.12.0:

> out = self.container.exec_run(command, user=user, demux=demux, environment=environment, workdir=workdir)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\models\containers.py", line 198, in exec_run
> exec_output = self.client.api.exec_start(
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
> return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\api\exec_api.py", line 169, in exec_start
> return self._read_from_socket(res, stream, tty=tty, demux=demux)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 413, in *read_from_socket
> return consume_socket_output(gen, demux=demux)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\socket.py", line 137, in consume_socket_output
> return six.binary_type().join(frames)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 407, in 
> gen = (data for (*, data) in gen)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\socket.py", line 94, in frames_iter_no_tty
> (stream, n) = next_frame_header(socket)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\socket.py", line 66, in next_frame_header
> data = read_exactly(socket, 8)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\socket.py", line 51, in read_exactly
> next_data = read(socket, n - len(data))
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\socket.py", line 35, in read
> return socket.recv(n)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\test-proj\build_en\lib\site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 117, in recv
> err, data = win32file.ReadFile(self._handle, bufsize)
> **pywintypes.error: (109, 'ReadFile', 'The pipe has been ended.')**

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3045 has been raised regarding this issue. Out of interest, what version of Python are you running?

Comment: I can reproduce this in a legacy Python 2.7 environment (Docker Python 4.4.4) but with Python 3+Docker Python 4.1.0 it works correctly.

Comment: I'm using python 3.9.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the problem - it seems is due to the latest docker desktop installed. If I downgrade from 4.12.0 to 4.11.1, error no more appears.

For downgrading, I've uninstalled from control panel and installed the 4.11.1 version downloading from https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-desktop-4111

Comment: Can confirm that the downgrade works. what a shitshow...

Answer (score 2):

For me the issues were resolved with the release of python docker SDK 6.0.1
https://github.com/docker/docker-py/releases/tag/6.0.1

After upgrading to this version the issue was resolved.
Everything now works with docker 4.13.1